# How can I add a callback function to Laravel Nova on storing a new resource?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

In Nova's ResourceStoreController.php, I can see this code:

```
$model = DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $resource) {
    [$model, $callbacks] = $resource::fill(
        $request, $resource::newModel()
    );

    if ($request->viaRelationship()) {
        $request->findParentModelOrFail()
                ->{$request->viaRelationship}()
                ->save($model);
    } else {
        $model->save();
    }

    ActionEvent::forResourceCreate($request->user(), $model)->save();

    collect($callbacks)->each->__invoke();

    return $model;
});
```

Which certainly looks like I should be able to set a callback function to it looking at this line:

```
collect($callbacks)->each->__invoke();
```

But how can I set a callback for a particular resource in Laravel Nova?

Basically, I want to trigger an event or callback when I store a new resource, but only when the resource is created through nova.

Comment: have you looked into using the event system https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/#resource-events ... if you want to respond to events only when the request is through Nova, they show how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Nova <= 2.x:**

I was able to accomplish this with a hidden field as of Nova's latest version, then just using normal laravel observers to check for the field on update.

**Updated November 2020 for Nova ^3.0+:**

You can now create a Laravel Observer specific for your Nova usages and tell Nova to use it by adding this to your NovaServiceProvider:

```
Nova::serving(function () {
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
});
```

Docs here:

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/#resource-events